# Apache eCharts: show/hide toolbox on event

Tags: javascript, echarts

How to show/hide the toolbox of a chart, where the zoom tool etc. is located, on a certain event?

[image: Toolbox is in the upper right corner]

I tried changing the "show" property, which didn't work:

```
chart.getOption().toolbox[0].show = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getOption()` only returns the value of your chart configuration. What you actually need to use is `setOption()` to change your chart's options :

```js
myChart.setOption({
    toolbox: { show: false }
})
```

[Here is a simple example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMmurGAJ4gCmRA5AMYCGYVA5sAE7m0A0J6AE2aMiAbVoBZGL1i0AKgFcqM2gHUqAlXIAWClQDEOEFQGVmphdFoBdEgF8-6MMGAAbAEbAMRVKVh5tYAB3IjAOJUdSADMqZgUOGmI_QWEALRcAWx9-ZPIcfABJaAEqb1loGGUc9Adq2CEwRgA1CCoQ5FgExgEAeWhXciIoxlc8Klha5NgMxlYIejlKRKQyJbFaVwhoZR5Zd0YOGwnIvwS8ZwSfSeS8RgA3Kiw8ApnWZbscj5rIvNxCJNIFGodDuIyUtHskTGRio_1EOV8yQaIlgogAjABWAAMuwATABmHGwXG4gAseLRAA5dmj8RiaaSAOx4gBsWOsJ0Ba1km22EL8X1gtjsAG4UCgMuQAMLaA5gAB0bzAqQ4AAoAJTymCqhibegAaxkUUs9EgMFgqpAB0YGTw6oBkplcvlYzAPXAUGgqsRfmcbk8ZRWAWCRAAhI7ZRwFUr3WavZq_R4vKJ2S7AkEJvZ1Sg7OqRUA) I created where the toolbox is shown/hidden each time you click the chart.

Comment: Easy as that. Thanks for the example!